# Align image center both vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've searched on here and I can not find a working solution for me. I've tried the following 
[Align image to the center both vertically and horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34209061/align-image-to-the-center-both-vertically-and-horizontally)
[Image center align vertically and horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481821/image-center-align-vertically-and-horizontally)
and a few more that i've found.

I've 2 columns. 1st has an image 500px X 500px 
2nd has text

I need the image center aligned both vertically and horizontally. and when on mobile view the image should appear above the text / centered.

```
<section id="what">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 box-image"><img class="box-image" src="http://chalkgallerylewes.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Placeholder-500x500px.png"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
      </p>
      <ul>
        <li>Placeholder list </li>
        <li>Placeholder list </li>
        <li>Placeholder list </li>
        <li>Placeholder list </li>
        <li>Placeholder list </li>
      </ul>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
      </p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
      </p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I've made a JF Fiddle with one of the ways i've been trying.

https://jsfiddle.net/davidstokes5000/rrdfLpyj/

Comment: the issue is with bootstrap i guess. You have relative position in the col-md-6

Comment: Is this the layout you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/rrdfLpyj/3/

Comment: No, the image should be side by side with the text on desktop.

Comment: @DaveYme It's side by side to me... what do you see?

Comment: @sol it's sitting above the text. Even when i stretch to full screen.

Comment: @sol I took your code and added it to mine and it worked. I think the fact you had 1 col-md-12 was effecting the look. But the css and adding the classes .box and .box__images has made it work. Thanks.

Comment: @DaveYme Great, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (no need to style the `img`). It should center the image above the text.

```
.box-image {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Try to use prefixes to support old browsers

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **flex** css. Apply `display:flex` to `row` class and for vertical align center of child items apply `align-items:center`.

To align image horizontally center apply bootstrap `center-block` class to `<img>`

> [Reference for **flex** css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

For responsive purpose use media query to set the `display: block` to the `row` to achieve your result.

Also there is horizontal scrolling in your code, to remove this wrap your `row` code into a div having `container-fluid` class.

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/71vk62mv/)**

```
#what {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#what .row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  #what .row {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

BTW there is a suggestion from @TemaniAfif to upgrade your **bootstrap3** to **bootstrap4**. It will be easy for you to solve issues like this in **bootstrap4**.

If you have any thoughts on using **bootstrap4** use this reference

> **[Bootstrap4 Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/)**

Comment: flex is good but i don't agree with it in this situation ... he is using Bootstrap V3 and by chaging the property fo some bootstrap classes you can create some conflict .. maybe changing anoher class than `row`

Comment: @TemaniAfif thats why I have used the parent id for this. I think flex will be good using less code rather than using absolute position

Comment: i agree it's good but i think it's better to lead him to upgrade to V4 version 
 (or add a comment for this) where there is already flex and he will see that it's more easier to deal with flex without even adding a CSS line ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, leading him to upgrade to V4 will be a good idea (i will add a comment). Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm going to test this out as well. I did get a working solution above but this looks good as well. I will try move to version 4. But for the moment I need v3.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#what{background-color: #fff;}
.box-image img{
display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
   
}
```

```html
<section id="what">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 box-image"><img class="box-image" src="http://chalkgallerylewes.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Placeholder-500x500px.png"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </p>

<ul>

<li>Placeholder list </li>
<li>Placeholder list </li>
<li>Placeholder list </li>
<li>Placeholder list </li>
<li>Placeholder list </li>
</ul>

<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </p>

  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Position absolute is doing the problem.

Comment: That doesn't work, The image is breaking into the upper section ( not in the code here ) It's not sitting in it's own div. It's the -250px